# How to keep block level when use position fixed?

Tags: css, css-position

When using `position: fixed`, the browser will remove the original place the layout thing have. How to prevent it?

In my case, the actual fixed position of a search appbar act as

[image]

Expecting act as.

[image]

Simulating css code.

```
.search-appbar-container {
  position: fixed;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}

.lef-arrow-icon-container`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 60px;
`;

.search-textfiled-container`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;

.add-icon-container`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;

.search-history-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.history-toggle-button`
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;

  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border: none;
  outline: none;

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
`;

.history-icon-container`
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5px;
  left: 0;

  width: 60px;
`;

.history-text-container`
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5px;
  left: 60px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Simulating html code.

```
<div>
  <div class="search-appbar-container">
    <div class="left-arrow-container>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="search-textfield-container>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="add-icon-container>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-history-div">
    <button class="history-toggle-button">
      <div class="history-icon-container>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="history-text-container>
        ...
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Have checkout all of my code, now I can find why this happened.

If the position of .search-appbar-container is `static`, the `absolute` position of history-icon-container and history-text-container are related the `relative` position of history-toggle-button, otherwise they are all related `fixed` position of search-appear-container.

Comment: You have to add your code into snippet which everybody can help you easily

Comment: Because I use some other language, only can provide the code fragment, sorry for  it.

Comment: In the above or/first code spelling of fixed is written as 'position: fiexed;'

Comment: @yuanlai Please provide your html code so we can help you further.

Comment: Simulate the css and html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and trying by myself, I have come out with a idea. If you want to keep fixed div with a block level, the proper way is to wrapper the same size parent div over it. Reflecting to my case, add the same width and height wrapper div upper `search-appbar-container`

```
.search-appbar-container-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}
.search-appbar-container {
  position: fixed;
  ...
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}
...
<div class="search-appear-container-wrapper">
  <div class="search-appbar-container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set margin-top or padding-top to .search-history-div or set .search-history-div{position: fixed;top: 48px}

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: This solution seems a workaround, you may computer the top distance each time, although thanks always XiongDie.

Comment: yes.if you don't want a centain  top distance every time,you can copy a seem DOM,one is {visibility:hidden},one is {display:fixed}